# Formatting Numeric Print Output Exception

Tags: java, printing, formatting, output, numeric

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException  
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)  
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)    
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)     
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)     
at Commission2.main(Commission2.java:38)
```

**It was working well at the beginning, until everything came crashing down. Now I need help. Anyone?**

import java.util.Scanner;//program needs scaanner
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

```
public class Commission2
{

public static void main(String args[])

    {

        //create Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //format decimal with two digits
    DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    //format decimal with three digits
    DecimalFormat threeDigits = new DecimalFormat("0.000");

    //declare all variables
    int size,count = 0;
    int pay = 200;
    double commission = 9/100;
    double result = 0;
    double item, itemtotal = 0;

    //get the limit of the data entry (data validation technique)
    do{
        System.out.printf("Enter the number of items :");
            size = input.nextInt();

    }while(size < 0);

    //data entry
    while (count < size) {

        System.out.print("Enter price of item #" +(count + 1) +": ");
            item = input.nextInt();


        /*Processing!*/
        itemtotal += item;
        ++count;


    }//end while
        result = (itemtotal * commission) + pay;

    System.out.printf("%s%d\n","The total earnings for this week is $",result);




    }
}
```

Comment: Commission2.main(Commission2.java:38), check at line 38, most probably  you are entering wrong data type for input

Comment: @Ankit Deshpande I don't think you're correct. I checked that before I posted. The reason I posted this is because iI'm stumped.

Comment: @Gerald Loo can you add the input for which it is failing?

Comment: @Andrea I apolgize if I'm being rude. It's that your comment/advice just added more error messages to the code.

Comment: Are you sure you are giving `integers` for your input? I tried your code and it works fine for integers input however it crashes in the last line `System.out.printf("%s%d\n","The total earnings for this week is $",result);`.  You need to change it to `System.out.printf("%s%f\n", "The total earnings for this week is $", result);` as Lucian Nut correctly answered.

Comment: All done! Thanks to everyone who helped and contributed! Apparently, I also cannot declare fractions. I fixed that and the double problem and now it's working! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 25 you are declaring `double item`, yet on line 38 you are trying to assign `input.nextInt()` to the variable item.

If you were to provide an `Integer` value (5) here, the code should work as intended. However when a `Double` is provided (5,12) an `InputMismatchException` exception will be thrown.

To fix this simply change this:

```
item = input.nextInt();
```

to this:

```
item = input.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.printf("%s%f\n", "The total earnings for this week is $", result);
```

Will work since %d goes only with integers while %f goes for both floats and doubles.

Comment: Yeap that's the only crash with the code, provided the values that the user inputs are integers!

Answer (score 0):

Since its failing at  item = input.nextInt();
it looks as if you tried with not an int value when you entered the value. Please check that. 
Why dont you post the input as well that you used?

Answer (score 0):

In your printf you are using decimal integer format to print the floats/doubles.
Instead of %d use %f.

[Please have a look at this link for more information](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)